# Multiple .cs files and access to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I'm trying to write my first program in C# without the use of a tutorial. To ensure that I adopt from the start good coding practices, I want to create each class in an different .cs file. However, I'm running into some troubles when trying to access the elements of the program in such an .cs file.

For example, I have an Form1.cs with an Label and a Start button. When clicking on the start button, a text should appear in the Label. So:

In **Form1.cs** I have:

```
namespace TestProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToLabel message = new WriteToLabel();
            message.WelcomeMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my separate **WriteToLabel.cs** file:

```
namespace TestProgram
{
    public class WriteToLabel
    {
        public void WelcomeMessage()
        {
            Form1 myForm = new Form1();
            //myForm..  --> myForm doesn't have an 'outputLabel'?
            outputLabel.Text = "Welcome!"; // This returns an error: 'The name outputLabel does not exits in the current context'.
        }
    }
}
```

*'outputLabel' is the (Name) I've given the label, and this is in accordance to the name in Form1.Designer.cs.
Both files are using the same components such as 'using System';.*

However, from my WriteToLabel.cs file I can't seem to access the Form which holds my program. I did manage to succeed to create different .cs files in an Console Application, which only added to my confusion. So, I have two questions:

**First**, how can I access the Form from a *separate* class (i.e. not an partial class) in a *separate* file?
**Second**, is this the good way to do it, or is it inefficient to create multiple instances of different classes?

Any thoughts or ideas are highly welcome,

Regards,

Comment: Why are you doing this without a tutorial? Tutorials help you learn the basics, don't discard them and expect us to fill the void.

Comment: Hi Lazarus, like I said, I've already practiced with tutorials, but now I'm trying on my own. And I haven't come across tutorials which deal with splitting projects in different .cs files. (Now that I see that the problem is an reference & access modifier problem, I could have found that on the internet or in my C# for Dummies or Learning C# book). Nonetheless, I agree with you that it is a pretty newbie-question. Btw, if you know any good tutorial sites (besides MSDN and CodeProject), let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer automatically creates controls as private fields, because of that your WriteToLabel class can't access it. You need to change that. 
Also a good start would be to change the class to something like that:

```
namespace TestProgram
{
    public class WriteToLabel
    {
        Form1 form;

        public WriteToLabel(Form1 form)
        {
            this.form = form;
        }

        public void WelcomeMessage()
        {
            //Form1 myForm = new Form1();
            //myForm..  --> myForm doesn't have an 'outputLabel'?
            form.outputLabel.Text = "Welcome!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jura, Just to add to bassfriend's answer and since you are looking out for good programming techniques, a better programming practice would be 1. keeping the variable "form" as private so the code would be "private Form1 form;" 2. it is not a good practice to expose controls as public/internal. It would be better if you expose a string public property and set "Text" value of the label in the "set" of the property.

Comment: @samar: I really like your idea, so thanks. The use of properties would be a good addition to the answers on this question. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @samar on 1. "Form1 form;" implies that the form will be private.
2. Good point

Comment: yeah bassfriend thats correct just wanted to point out that it would be a good programming practice if we mention the variable as "private" explicitly thats all.

Comment: @samar: Could you elaborate some more on your get/set property to change the label? I just can seem to get it to work, because editing the VS generated Form1.Designer.cs gives a lot of conflicts. And I'm also trying to implement the tip from Matthew by *not* creating a new instance of Form1 (so editing the textlabel in another class with a new instance of Form1 is not 'good'). Off course I can make the label text public, but that's not good coding practice either. :S Or is it? So, any thoughts are highly welcomed. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're actually instantiating a *new* instance of `Form1`, whereas you need to pass in a reference to your existing instance:

```
public void WelcomeMessage(Form1 form)
{
    form.outputLabel.Text = "Welcome";
}
```

You also need to ensure that `outputLabel` is a public (or internal) property/field of `Form1` so you can set the value accordingly.  Then the calling code is slightly different:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteToLabel message = new WriteToLabel();
    message.WelcomeMessage(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Matthew. You're right, I was needlessly instantiating instead of referring. Also thanks for further elaboration, that made it less abstract. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `Form1.outputLabel` has **public** or **internal** visibility.

You only need something like a `LabelWriter` class if the class is going to share a significant amount of state or private methods. If all you have is a bunch of methods that set properties on separate objects, you might as well just keep it as a method on the same object (in this case the Form1 object):

```
void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        displayWelcomeMessage();
    }

void displayWelcomeMessage()
    {
       this.outputLabel = "Welcome!";
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mark, good idea! For this example it would be indeed more efficient to keep it in the Form1 object. Part of the question was also to get an better understanding of splitting an C# project in multiple files. Thanks for responding!